# Hive [Error 10025]: Expression not in GROUP BY key name

Tags: sql, hive, cloudera

I'm trying to select records defined by key-terms in a variable within a group.

name is a string with key terms interested.

groups are defined by the combo of id1 and id2.

I'm interested in extract records by groups that contain the key terms.

```
select id1, id2, name
   case
    when name LIKE '%LOAD_TIME' then 1
    when name LIKE '%LOGIN_SESSION_TIME' then 1
   end as b_flag
   from df1
   group by id1, id2
   having (sum(b_flag) > 0 )
```

df1:

```
id1  id2  name                               
1     1    xxxLOAD_TIME
1     1    xxxLOGIN_LOGIN_SESSION_TIMExxx
1     1    xxxxSome other timexxxx
2     2    xxSome other timex
3     1    xxxLOAD_TIME
3     1    xxSome other timexx
```

After creating b_flag the new dataset should look like:

```
id1  id2  name                             b_flag   
1     1    xxxLOAD_TIME                      1
1     1    xxxLOGIN_LOGIN_SESSION_TIMExxx    1
1     1    xxxxSome other timexxxx   
2     2    xxSome other timex
3     1    xxxLOAD_TIME                      1
3     1    xxSome other timexx
```

Desired output:

```
   id1  id2  name                             b_flag   
    1     1    xxxLOAD_TIME                      1
    1     1    xxxLOGIN_LOGIN_SESSION_TIMExxx    1
    1     1    xxxxSome other timexxxx   
    3     1    xxxLOAD_TIME                      1
    3     1    xxSome other timexx
```

I do not see what is wrong with my code, but I have been getting the same error:

> [Error 10025]: Expression not in GROUP BY key name

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with window functions:

```
select id1, id2, name, b_flag
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        case when name LIKE '%LOAD_TIME' or name LIKE '%LOGIN_SESSION_TIME' then 1 end b_flag,
        sum(case when name LIKE '%LOAD_TIME' or name LIKE '%LOGIN_SESSION_TIME' then 1 end) 
            over(partition by id1, id2) sum_b_flag
    from mytable t
) t
where sum_b_flag > 0
```

The inner query checks if the current row matches the criteria, and computes a window sum for the flag over records having the same `(id1, id2)`.

If you don't want to repeat the expression that computes the flag, you can use an additional subquery:

```
select id1, id2, name, b_flag
from (
    select t.*, sum(b_flag) over(partition by id1, id2) sum_b_flag
    from (
        select 
            t.*, 
            case when name LIKE '%LOAD_TIME' or name LIKE '%LOGIN_SESSION_TIME' then 1 end b_flag,
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
where sum_b_flag > 0
```

Comment: This maybe too much, but would be able to also take a look at my other post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740785/transpose-dataset-in-hive Thank you, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: @lydias: tell me, does the above query works fine for your use case?

Comment: could I let you know by tmr ? I just got off work , I’ll be able to let you know by tomorrow morning.

Comment: Sure @lydias, no pb.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```sql
select 
    main.id1, 
    main.id2, 
    main.name,
    case
        when main.name LIKE '%LOAD_TIME' then 1
        when main.name LIKE '%LOGIN_SESSION_TIME' then 1
    end as b_flag
from 
    df1 main
    left semi join (
        select distinct id1, id2 from df1 
        where (case
            when name LIKE '%LOAD_TIME' then 1
            when name LIKE '%LOGIN_SESSION_TIME' then 1
        end)=1 ) f 
on main.id1=f.id1 and main.id2=f.id2
```

Comment: Do I need to include name in group by?

Comment: The dataset is empty ..but the error disappeared. I also checked name variable, the values do contain defined key terms.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I tweaked my answer- now it should do the trick

Comment: Invalid table alias or column reference 'main'

Comment: Sorry, yet another tweak!

Comment: thank you , I’ll test out the codes tmr . You guys are awesome .